# Push data from one Kafka server to another

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I need to push data from multiple Kafka producers to a seperate Kafka broker. Say I have 3 Kafka servers. From Kafka 1 and 2, I need to push the data to Kafka 3 like below, is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kafka has built in replication across brokers. Your producer can only write to one broker at any time for any topic in the cluster.

If you have separate clusters, use MirrorMaker to replicate topics

Answer (score 0):

There are some misunderstood in your questions.

### 1. There is no Kafka Server

Kafka is a cluster, which means that all "servers" work together as a unique server. This means that when you send a message to a Kafka Cluster, you don't know which broker will accept this message.

You need to use the correct names for questions. When you say "Kafka broker" you mean a Kafka instance in a cluster. There is no "Kafka Server".

### 2. Do you need to replicate your data? Or just send the same message to two Kafka Clusters?

You need to replicate your message, this means that you have just one message that exists in two brokers, you need to set your topic replication.

### 3. Do you need the same message in two Clusters?

Use [Mirror Maker](https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/connect/mirror)

Comment: A broker is a server. Not everyone needs to know terms. They are not all unique. And yes, producers do know which broker will get any record... The partitioner is client side logic

Comment: Broker and Server are different kinds of software. The word server works with a Client/Server architecture which a Kafka Cluster do not match. Kafka is a cluster because it works as a single piece of software event in a distributed deployment. I used these concepts to answer, as this is a QA.

Comment: The Kafka source code literally starts a Java ServerSocket. A server is simply defined as a networked machine that opens some port. Therefore, a "Kafka server" is **also** a broker. Why not? It's not required to be installed as a cluster. And producers/consumers are called clients, so yes, it has client/server architecture, just not completely request/reply like an HTTP server/client

Comment: ServerSocket just means that it listens to the socket. When we talk Client-Server we talk about some elements that ONLY send requests and elements that ONLY answer these requests. When I have an open socket both can send requests. I'm based on this paper:  https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/net_arch_styles.htm

Comment: And my comments are based on this https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_nutshell

Comment: Sure, and look at what this says: "Some of these servers form the storage layer, called the brokers". This means that the running Kafka instance should be called a broker, the documentation refers to everything as Kafka and the broker is what consumers/producer connects with. I say "there is no server" because the drawing is conceptuality wrong, we have a cluster or just a broker.